# I need a batch script read first line from a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need a batch script read first line from a text file. Then if some line ends with .part1 extension then read the next line. if the next line do not have .part# extension in the end then do some actions with the .part files. So basically those will be urls ending with .part1, .part2 and then I need to download those .part files extract through cmd and some files do not have .part extension.

Example,

```
new.txt

http://abcd.com/abcd.part1
http://abcd.com/abcd.part2
http://abcd.com/abcd.part3
http://abcd.com/xyz.zip
```

So I need to download abcd.part1, abcd.part2 and abcd.part3 at once, then extract and delete the part files.

That's what I wanna do

After this point I'm unable to proceed. If someone can just give a code to print all the part files the downloading and unzipping can be done me.

I mean in a sequenced part1..partn I need to print part1..partn

if not found any partn at EOL then print the next line to a file then again search if there's any part file if found print all part1..partn to a file.

```
@echo off
cd /D %SCP_HOME%
setlocal enableextensions
set count=0
set i=0
for %%x in (*) do set /a count+=1
echo %count%
for /r %%f in (*) do (
    echo %%~nxf
    head 1 %%~nxf
    more +1 %%~nxf > %count%-1%%~nxf
)
endlocal
```

Comment: The command `FINDSTR /ERC:"\.part[0-9]*" <new.txt` will produce a list of lines which contain `.part*` at the end of the line.

Comment: HI @lit but I want to list line by line so that I can download those part files and extract them. That will consume less memory. Cause after unizipping those files I need to zip them, upload and delete everything.

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate over the lines that contain "part*" at the end of the line. Will this get you started?

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "THE_FILE=new.txt"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`TYPE "%THE_FILE%"`) DO (
    ECHO %%~a | FINDSTR /RC:"http://.*\.part[0-9]*" >NUL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        ECHO This line matches
        ECHO %%~a
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO This line does not match
        ECHO %%~a
    )
)
```

Comment: I believe the files are .part1.rar or .part1.zip like this

Comment: Thanks @lit. I believe I can do the rest now. If anything's needed I'll post here.

Comment: By the way one more help needed. What if I just want check current line for "\.part[0-9]*". If found then do something else do another action

Comment: I basically need to check line by line.

Comment: @BinayakChatterjee - Revised answer to check line-by-line.